# Express Jade link external url

Tags: node.js, url, express, hyperlink, pug

I have an express app, I have a template that spits a link like:

index.jade:

```
var url = 'google.com'
a(href="{{= url }}") {{= url }}
```

However, it produces a link to:

```
http://localhost/google.com
```

And not:

```
google.com
```

What I really need is to create a link to the external url.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `var url = 'https://www.google.com'`

Comment: god. what a dumdum. Thanks! @BidhanA